# How to add a Image into a GridView in Visual Web Part from Sharepoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, gridview, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to add a Image Object into a GridView? I did the following, but it's not working... Just the text column works!

```
    DataTable table;
    Image blueStar = new Image();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        blueStar = ImageBlueStar;

        table= new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("Star Image", typeof(Image));
        table.Columns.Add("Some Text");

        table.Rows.Add(blueStar, "Something");
        table.Rows.Add(blueStar, "Something");

        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

With the code above my GridView appears, but just with the text column.

Comment: What do you have in you markup? i think you should create BoundControl in gridview markup and add html markup to display image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded a way to do that!
I changed my code like below:

```
DataTable table;
Image blueStar = new Image();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   blueStar = ImageBlueStar;

   table= new DataTable();

   table.Columns.Add("Title Text");

   tabela.Rows.Add("URL FROM IMAGE", "SOME TEXT");

   SPGridView novaGrid = new SPGridView();
   novaGrid.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
   novaGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
   novaGrid.Columns.Add(new ImageField { DataImageUrlField = "Title Text"});


   Controls.Add(novaGrid);
   novaGrid.DataBind();

}
```